# Check image compression used in PDF document?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

Is it possible to find out what compression algorithms have been used for images in a PDF document?

Comment: If this includes paid-for software, use [Acrobat Pro](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/47218/30216), which has an Object Inspector.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pdfimages -list $file` on Unix/Linux systems, on Windows maybe you can install poppler to get access to the tool (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages).
Note that this is a command line application, without graphical user interface. Its output will look like

```
page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0 image    1240  1753  gray    1   8  image  no         8  0   150   150  301K  14%
   2     1 image    1240  1753  gray    1   8  image  no        22  0   150   150  281K  13%
   3     2 image    1240  1753  gray    1   8  image  no        36  0   150   150  336K  16%
```

Where the `enc` column tells you the encoding algorithm, the possible values are listed in the [manpage for `pdfimages`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfimages).

Comment: note xpdf web page seems to have windows and mac binaries

Comment: btw, I was confused because the version of pdfimages I had, did not contain the "-list" option.

turns out the project was forked back in 2011, so you are going to want pdfimages from Poppler, not Glyph & Cog's xpdf

Comment: Check the actual man page of `pdfimages` as the link posted in this answer does not even document the `-list` option

Answer (score 5):

Sort of.

If you open a PDF in a text editor, you'll find a line like this for each image:

```
<</Subtype/Image/Length 7986/Filter/FlateDecode/BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace 34 0 R/Width 368/Height 110/Type/XObject>>stream
...
```

This image uses the FlateDecode filter, "a commonly used filter based on the zlib/deflate algorithm (a.k.a. gzip, but not zip)"

```
<</Subtype/Image/Length 892/Filter/DCTDecode/BitsPerComponent 8/ColorSpace 34 0 R/Width 44/Height 23/Type/XObject>>stream
...
```

This image uses the DCTDecode filter, "a lossy filter based on the JPEG standard"

Filter definitions are from the [Portable Document Format Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format), which has a list of all the supported filters.

However, it can be difficult to work out which image is which in a text editor - the objects do not necessarily occur in reading order. Breaking the PDF into single pages might help here.

I think [Enfocus Pitstop Pro](http://www.enfocus.com/en/products/pitstop-pro), an Acrobat plugin, may well give you this info (along with dimensions, position, DPI etc) in its object inspector, but I no longer have it, and can't seem to find any mention of this specific attribute in their manual.

Comment: Acrobat also has a myriad of predefined preflight reports. Not sure if they are available in the free version (?)

Comment: Note that PNG also uses the DEFLATE compression algorithm (zlib is an implementation of DEFLATE).  So you can think of the first example as being *like* a PNG image in many respects such as how well it will compress.

Comment: @horatio: They are not. Also the free version is called "Adobe Reader" not "Adobe Acrobat Reader" these days.

Comment: I thought it was Acrobat X or AcrobatZ or something :)

Comment: It's always been confusing. It's currently Adobe Reader X, Adobe Acrobat X, Adobe Acrobat X Pro. What really annoys me is when people refer to "Adobe" when they mean a single app.

Comment: @e100 Yes! Every time a client says, "I opened it in Adobe" I have to stop and think what they're talking about.